# installing fbprophet in docker file docker build on M1 Mac does not work

Tags: installation, dockerfile, apple-m1, facebook-prophet, pystan

Does anyone know how to install fbprophet in the docker file for the Mac M1 pro ? As I am unable to install it citing

below is instructions saved in a text file named "dockerfile":

**FROM jupyter/scipy-notebook:python-3.9.7
RUN pip install fbprophet
ENV PYTHONPATH "${PYTHONPATH}:/home/jovyan/work"
RUN echo "export PYTHONPATH=/home/jovyan/work" >> ~/.bashrc
WORKDIR /home/jovyan/work**

Followed by entering the command line "**docker build -t fbprophet-notebook:latest .**"

the information shows:

**Successfully built pymeeus
#6 18.13 Failed to build fbprophet pystan
#6 18.57 Installing collected packages: setuptools-git, pymeeus, korean-lunar-calendar, ephem, pystan, hijri-converter, convertdate, LunarCalendar, holidays, cmdstanpy, fbprophet
#6 18.97   Running setup.py install for pystan: started
#6 22.85   Running setup.py install for pystan: finished with status 'error'**

I tried enter this command line:

**docker run  -dit --rm --name adv_dsi_lab_2 -p 8888:8888 -e JUPYTER_ENABLE_LAB=yes -v "$PWD":/home/jovyan/work fbprophet-notebook:latest .**

The result was:
**(base) user@user-MacBook-Pro adv_dsi_lab_2 % docker run  -dit --rm --name adv_dsi_lab_2 -p 8888:8888 -e JUPYTER_ENABLE_LAB=yes -v "$PWD":/home/jovyan/work fbprophet-notebook:latest .
Unable to find image 'fbprophet-notebook:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for fbprophet-notebook, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied.
See 'docker run --help'.**

Where did I go wrong?